# Cheap global shutter cameras with external synchronization

Tags: slam, computer-vision, cameras, stereo-vision

Please recommend cameras for multi-camera setup satisfying the following conditions:

- Relatively cheap (up to 100$ per camera).
- Global shutter.
- No filters on lenses or pixels.
- Resolution of 1 MP or higher.
- Capture frequency of 25 Hz or higher.
- Wide field of view, at least 80° horizontally, ideally ~110°.
- Ability to synchronize frame capture using external source.
- (Optional) USB 3 interface for data transfer and Video4Linux compatibility.

The setup is planned for visual SLAM research. Currently we use Intel RealSense cameras, but they have the following drawbacks for us:

- Redundant hardware: color camera, IR projector, IMU, proprietary ASIC for data processing.
- IR cameras have short baseline (60-90 mm).
- Cameras face in the same direction, while we would like to work with partially overlapping fields of view.
- D455 sensor uses Bayer-pattern on its "infrared" cameras.
- `librealsense2` is somewhat bloated and has not the greatest C API.

We also work with cameras produced by The Imaging Source, but unfortunately they are more expensive than we would like.

It would be really nice if you will recommend camera models with which you have hands-on experience, but of course it is not mandatory.

Comment: shopping questions are off topic here ... also, product recommendation requests are off topic

Comment: you can choose a camera, provide the datasheet, and ask if the camera is suitable for your application .... that would be on topic